# How to do a search on an array of string arrays with sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query in sql:

```
AND EXISTS (
 SELECT 1
 FROM "attribute"
 WHERE "attribute"."productId" = p.id
 GROUP BY "attribute"."productId"
 HAVING array_agg(DISTINCT "attribute".value) @> ${attributes}
)
```

This search works well, as the `attributes` parameter is an array of strings

example: `attributes = ["Car", "Black"]`

But now, the `attributes` is an array of string arrays, example:

example: `attributes = [ ["Car", "Bike"], ["White", "Black"], ]`

And in the search, I need an adjustment, so that it goes through the `attributes` array, and the `"attribute".value`, contains 1 or more values ​​of each item in the attributes array, and should only return a product, if each item of the string array has at least 1 value in `"attribute".value`.

the `"attribute".value` is an array of strings.

I'm using postgres

Expected behavior

I receive in the `attributes` parameter `[["Car", "Bike"], ["Blue", "Red"]]`

It should only return records that include in the `"attribute".value` the value `"Car"` or `"Bike"` and `"Blue"` or `"Red"`

Must contain at least 1 or more records within each string array

Comment: You are going to need to provide a more detailed explanation of  *..."attribute".value, contains 1 or more values ​​of each item in the attributes array, and should only return a product, if each item of the string array has at least 1 value in "attribute".value*. Preferably with example input data and expected output. Add as update to question.

Comment: A quick and dirty possible solution `select array['Car', 'Red'] <@ string_to_array(array_to_string(array[['Car', 'Bike'], ['Blue', 'Red']], ','), ','); t` vs `select array['Car', 'Green'] <@ string_to_array(array_to_string(array[['Car', 'Bike'], ['Blue', 'Red']], ','), ','); f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution, instead of using an array of string arrays, I modified it to an array of strings, separated by commas:

Before:
`attributes = [ ["Car", "Bike"], ["White", "Black"] ]`

then: `attributes = ["Car,Bike","White,Black"]`

How I solved it with sql:

```
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM "attribute"
    WHERE "attribute".."productId" = p.id
    GROUP BY "attribute"."productId"
    HAVING array_agg(DISTINCT "attribute".value) && ALL (
    SELECT string_to_array(value, ',')
    FROM unnest(${attributes}::text[]) AS value
   )
)
```